# how do I replicate matplotlib normalisation functionality imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am implementing neural style transfer. My objective is to create a timelapse of the training process. However, the generated image that the algorithm outputs falls out of the range [0, 1]. I tried subtracting the min and dividing by the max but the resulting image turns out whit-ish but I also noticed that when using Matplotlib to show the image the following warning come out:

*Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).*

and the resulting image comes fantastic, so what does it do exactly?

here is my code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AzGGpAtGi-kMIGl32y9U8PCg7ERh1cik?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imshow()` does just a linear transformation, mapping the range `[vmin, vmax]` to `[0, 1]`.  It's a function like `f(x) = (x - vmin) / (vmax - vmin)`. When `vmin` or `vmax` aren't provided, they are calculated as the minimum and maximum of the given data.

More elaborate mappings are also possible, as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I guess so, do you have any explanation why the rendered video looks whitish?

Comment: Your code is a bit too extensive for me to run at the moment. You set your own `vmin` to be larger than the minimum (and similar for `vmax`). That way `imshow` will show everything equal or lower to `vmin` with the lowest color. You could also explicitly call `img = np.clip(img, my_vmin, my_vmax)` to do the clipping.

Comment: that would probably work, thank you so much, I didn't realise there was such a function